# Exporting comma delimited data from a very large table

Tags: mysql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to get all the data from a very large table from a remote host having around 13million entries into a text file. I have tried the following command but after sometime process gets killed and shows a message called "Killed." in the console. 
 `mysql --user=username --password -h host -e "select * from db.table_name" >> output_file.txt` 
My primary goal is to copy data from mysql to redshift, which I am doing it by getting all the data with "," delimited int a text file uploading it on s3 and executing `COPY` query on redshift.
P.S for small tables the above command is working properly but not for large tables.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) instead. It can be parameterized to output CSV if I recall correctly. I haven't tried this myself, so you might want to check the docs, but this should work:

```
mysqldump --user=username --password -h host \
--fields-terminated-by="," --fields-enclosed-by="\"" --lines-terminated-by="\n" \
dbname tablename > output_file.txt
```

If that does not work, you could try SELECT INTO OUTFILE. You will need to do that directly on the MySQL host like this:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/data.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM db.table_name
```

Comment: If you could provide the command for the first option exporting to csv file would be very helpful. I have no access for the files other than the database so the second option wont be much of help.